# Trigger a method in every ecs instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I need to call a method when an event occurs in every ECS instance. If a method is Trigger in any instance it triggers a method in the other tasks and other services.

I can use an instance of elastic cache with Redis and the pub/sub, but I don't want to create an entire instance for this because is only for two services with 2 tasks in each one, and I don't need to use the Redis cache at this moment. Can anyone help me with a solution? I tried to use SNS, but those services don't use servers, so I can't use the HTTP protocol of the SNS.

Comment: You will need some sort of pub/sub architecture for this to work. You could look into using SNS instead of Redis. SNS for this use case would probably be free, or very close to free.